# Why is getting different values for longitude and latitude in android?

Tags: android, gps, geolocation, network-programming, location

I am doing application, we are in inside the room or not. I have to stored 4 corner values means doing polygon. But i cant get exactly value in the same position, it gets different values in the same position. How it get solution this problem??

Code:

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

 Button btnShowLocation;    
 TextView tvLat;
 TextView tvLang;
 TextView tvInsideRoom;

 dbHandler myDbHelper;

// GPSTracker class
GPSTracker gps;


Handler  mHandler1;



    tvInsideRoom = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.insideRoom);        
    btnShow = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnShow);

 // show location button click event
    btnShow.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {   
            mHandler1 = new Handler();

            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    while (true) {
                        try {
                            Thread.sleep(100);
                            mHandler1.post(new Runnable() {

                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                                    // creating GPS Class object
                                GPSTracker gps = new GPSTracker (MainActivity.this);

                                    // check if GPS location have some values
                                    if (gps.canGetLocation()) {

                                        double currentlat = gps.getLatitude();
                                        double currentlong = gps.getLongitude();

                                        tvLat = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.lat);
                                        tvLang = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.lang);

                                        tvLat.setText(""+currentlat);
                                        tvLang.setText(""+currentlong);

                                        boolean boolFlag = myDbHelper.isInsideRoom(currentlat,currentlong);

                                        tvInsideRoom.setText("");

                                        if(boolFlag)
                                            tvInsideRoom.setText("You are in inside Room");   
                                        else 
                                            tvInsideRoom.setText(""+boolFlag);

                                    } else {
                                        // no current location
                                        gps.showSettingsAlert();
                                    }
                                }
                            });
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            // TODO: handle exception
                        }
                    }
                }
            }).start(); 
        }
    }); }
```

GPSTracker.java

```
public class GPSTracker extends Service implements LocationListener {

private final Context mContext;

// flag for GPS status
boolean isGPSEnabled = false;

// flag for network status
boolean isNetworkEnabled = false;

// flag for GPS status
boolean canGetLocation = false;

Location location; // location
double latitude; // latitude
double longitude; // longitude

// The minimum distance to change Updates in meters
private static final long MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES = 1; // 10 meters

// The minimum time between updates in milliseconds
private static final long MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES = 1; // 1 minute

// Declaring a Location Manager
protected LocationManager locationManager;

public GPSTracker(Context context) {
    this.mContext = context;
    getLocation();
}

public Location getLocation() {
    try {
        locationManager = (LocationManager) mContext.getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

        // getting GPS status
        isGPSEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

        // getting network status
        isNetworkEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

        if (!isGPSEnabled && !isNetworkEnabled) {
            // no network provider is enabled
        } else {
            this.canGetLocation = true;
            // First get location from Network Provider
            if (isNetworkEnabled) {
                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,
                        MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                Log.d("Network", "Network");
                if (locationManager != null) {
                    location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
                    if (location != null) {
                        Log.d("Accuracy1 := ", ""+location.getAccuracy());
                        latitude = location.getLatitude();
                        longitude = location.getLongitude();
                    }
                }
            }
            // if GPS Enabled get lat/long using GPS Services
            if (isGPSEnabled) {
                if (location == null) {
                    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                            MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                    Log.d("GPS Enabled", "GPS Enabled");
                    if (locationManager != null) {
                        location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                        if (location != null) {
                            Log.d("Accuracy2 := ", ""+location.getAccuracy());
                            latitude = location.getLatitude();
                            longitude = location.getLongitude();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return location;
}

/**
 * Stop using GPS listener
 * Calling this function will stop using GPS in your app
 * */
public void stopUsingGPS(){
    if(locationManager != null){
        locationManager.removeUpdates(GPSTracker.this);
    }      
}

/**
 * Function to get latitude
 * */
public double getLatitude(){
    if(location != null){
        latitude = location.getLatitude();
    }

    // return latitude
    return latitude;
}

/**
 * Function to get longitude
 * */
public double getLongitude(){
    if(location != null){
        longitude = location.getLongitude();
    }         
    // return longitude
    return longitude;
}

/**
 * Function to check GPS/wifi enabled
 * @return boolean
 * */
public boolean canGetLocation() {
    return this.canGetLocation;
}

/**
 * Function to show settings alert dialog
 * On pressing Settings button will lauch Settings Options
 * */
public void showSettingsAlert(){
    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);

    // Setting Dialog Title
    alertDialog.setTitle("GPS is settings");

    // Setting Dialog Message
    alertDialog.setMessage("GPS is not enabled. Do you want to go to settings menu?");

    // On pressing Settings button
    alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Settings", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int which) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
            mContext.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    // on pressing cancel button
    alertDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        dialog.cancel();
        }
    });

    // Showing Alert Message
    alertDialog.show();
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    this.location = location;
}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
    return null;
}}
```

Comment: may be accuracy differ

Comment: @nizammoidu same result gets either remove accuracy method.

Comment: you cant set accuracy. how much difference are you seeing? if u need pin pointing you will have to deal with accuracy, it might differ same place over time due to different factors playing to fix GPS position

Answer (score 3):

The accuracy of location tracking can vary vastly. What you are trying to achieve will never work because of an insufficient accuracy. Especially inside a room, but even with GPS.

Depending on where you are, network cell-towers, wifi or GPS will be used to determine the current location, and all with a different accuracy. Even outside, it usually takes a few seconds until you get a GPS fix.

Use [getAccuracy()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html#getAccuracy%28%29) to check if your location is somewhat useful with the current fix.

Comment: i am using GPS & remove with getAccuracy(). get different values in same place

Comment: Yes, like I said accuracy and therefore location will vary. Trust me, location tracking with smartphones is most likely not accurate enough for what you want to achieve. Outside with GPS maybe (http://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2013/07/15/smartphones-tablets-and-gps-accuracy/), but even then locations will differ. No chance inside a room.

Comment: Means inside room, it will get differ value.. I am using Samsung Galaxy SII for this application..

Comment: That's what it means, yes. Inside a room and probably even outside a room, you will get different values because your location will NEVER be 100% accurate.

Comment: Ok.. What is solution for this?? Should I get value for room outside of room??...

Comment: There is no real solution Nitin. What you want to do will not work with 100% acurracy. Your location will always be a few meters off: http://www.gps.gov/systems/gps/performance/accuracy/

Comment: the solution for you is to NOT USE A PHONE. If you want to measure a room you have to use old fashion way, with a measure tape or one of those laser gadgets you can get on Amazon. But a phone (or any other GPS device) it will not work.